# looping on iterables, return best practice

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Every now and then I fall on this pattern when looping through an array:

```
for a in b:  
  if a==y:    
   #do somethinng
    return 1
```

there is no else statement because I need to check the full array for `a==y` (let's say a is name in a dir list) before returning anything.

It would also be a good idea to return something only if no element in the array fulfills the condition `a==y`

How should I  re organize the code in this sense?

How do I tell the caller if the loop doesn't 'succeed' in finding 'y'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would probably be a good idea to return something only if no element in the array fulfills the condition x==b but I don't know how to re organize the code in this sense.

The usual thing is to put the `return` reflecting the fact that nothing matched after the loop:

```
for a in b:  
  if a==y:    
   #do somethinng
    return 1
return 0 # or whatever
```

In some cases, it may be appropriate to throw an exception after the loop instead, if the fact that nothing matched within the loop is an *exceptional* condition, not a normal case.

---

Please be sure to check out [navneethc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62610587/157247) using `any` as well.

Comment: thanks a lot, i was very confused. guess this is another question but not sure about return vs throw error. sorry that i can't upvote

Comment: @misternobody - Happy to help! Re `return` vs. `throw`, it's a judgement call. Basically: If not finding the thing is **unexpected**, you usually throw an error. But if it's expected, you return a "not found" flag value of some kind instead. The difference to the calling code is whether it has to handle the flag value in the main logic of the code, or if the main logic of the code is uninterrupted but they have to handle a possible exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting to encounter `y` only once or only take into account its first occurrence (given that you have a return statement within the condition), then here's another method:

```
if any(a == y for a in b):
    #do something
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Nice to see a Python-specific answer. I'm intrigued by `a == y for a in b`. Is that a function or lambda or...?

Comment: It's a comprehension, generally speaking, and the fundamental idea behind it is found in other languages too, especially those oriented towards functional programming. You can enclose the expression in `[]` to get a list comp.; within `()` to get a generator comp. (NOT a tuple). Using `{}` will get you either a set or a dictionary comprehension depending upon how you format things inside. The same behaviour can be achieved using the `map` function but comprehensions are preferred for their clarity when used properly and, in some cases, speed.

Comment: Ah! Of course. I'd heard of them but didn't recognize the syntax (as I don't do Python [yet]). Thanks!!